# How to run a job dependent on another in csh unix

Tags: unix, operating-system, aix

I have a job which is dependent on another job. Once the previous job is finished and the correspondent log file is created with EOJ at the end of the log, I have to look for the EOJ in the log. If found, my job would run.

I am running this in csh, AIX. Please help me the code for this.

Comment: Can you just run it like `job1 && job2`?

Comment: say primary job is Job1, which is already scheduled and running. I am writing a new job2 which will read the log of job1 and once the EOJ is found in log of job1, job2 would run. So basically in job2, i have to write a code to wait for the EOJ found in log of Job1 and then do the task in job2.

Comment: Scheduled and running how? By far the simplest thing would be to just chain the commands and look at the result code with `&&`, rather than parsing a log. Next best option I suppose would be to grep and chain off that; something like `tail -f log | grep -q EOJ && job2`

Comment: job1 is scheduled in crontab in a specific time to run. So job2 would be scheduled after that only.

Comment: So why not just update the crontab to chain them? It sounds like you’re trying to schedule them independently when they’re not actually independent.

Comment: yeah, i can do that. but sometimes, it takes longer to finish. so how would i know, when it is finished?

Comment: That's what `&&` does. It means "Run this and wait for it to finish, then run this next thing if the first thing succeeded". As opposed to `||`, which means "Run this and wait for it to finish, and then run this other thing, even if the first thing failed".